# How to change number font in equation to text number font in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, equations, number

I am using a template which is very long and has a lot of no-English characters. I found the numbers' font in the equations is different from the numbers in the text, so I hope to make the numbers' font in the equations to the numbers font of the text. But I don't know what numbers' font of the text is. In this situation, is there a way to change the numbers' font in equations to the numbers' font in the text? So, I can't make an MWE here. This is the [`cls` file](https://bthc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/mr_iem_im/EcqGzLW_MjtIte7HAJl7UKoB0J3MfWnKv_EeuMZ3TIzzng?e=rh72iL) and all [the files](https://github.com/whutug/whu-thesis/releases/tag/v0.6e). Run the file named `whu-thesis-demo.tex`. Run this file,

> `555` and `$55$`

is different:
[image][image][image]

I want to change `$55$` to `55`.

```
\RequirePackage { unicode-math }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__whu_fontset:n #1
  { \cs_gset_eq:Nc \__whu_set_font: { __whu_set_font_ #1 : } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__whu_cjk_fontset:n #1
  { \cs_gset_eq:Nc \__whu_set_cjk_font: { __whu_set_cjk_font_ #1 : } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__whu_math_fontset:n #1
  { \cs_gset_eq:Nc \__whu_set_math_font: { __whu_set_math_font_ #1 : } }

\keys_define:nn { whu / style }
  {
    font .choices:nn =
      { times , xits , termes }
      { \__whu_fontset:n { \l_keys_choice_tl } },
    % 西文字体

    math-font .choices:nn =
      { xits , termes }
      { \__whu_math_fontset:n { \l_keys_choice_tl } },
    % 数学字体

    cjk-font .choices:nn =
      { windows , mac , fandol , overleaf }
      { \__whu_cjk_fontset:n { \l_keys_choice_tl } },
    % 中文字体
  }
% 西文字体
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__whu_set_font_times:
  { \setmainfont { Times ~ New ~ Roman } [ Ligatures = Rare ] }

% XITS % 字体安装在 TeX 发行版下，必须使用文件名调用
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__whu_set_font_xits:
  {
    \setmainfont { XITS }
      [
        Extension      = .otf,
        UprightFont    = * - Regular,
        BoldFont       = * - Bold,
        ItalicFont     = * - Italic,
        BoldItalicFont = * - BoldItalic
      ]
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Without knowing what document class, packages, settings, etc., you're using, any answer we give would be based on pure guesswork and may not work in your actual use case.

Comment: @frabjous As they set fonts in `cls` file, which is too difficult for me to read. I just need to change the numbers' font in equations to that in the text. Is there a line of code that should be added before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Math mode uses a different font mechanism to text mode. Not one line of code. Do you use `unicode-math` package? Or does the class define math fonts?

Comment: @Cicada In the `tex` file, `5` and `$5$` are different fonts. I want to change `5` in the `$5$`  to the font of `5` in the text.

Comment: In addition to previous comments, it's necessary to know what document class you're using; without that information, it's impossible to do anything but guess.  For best assistance, please provide a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem described, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}.  That allows potential helpers to copy and paste the code to experiment.

Comment: The .cls isn't public so you could provide a link to it? Can you at least say whether you're using pdflatex or xelatex? Your PDF viewer should be able to tell you want fonts are embedded in the document. If you're using pdflatex, and I have to guess completely without further knowledge, you could try `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}`, but that may cause other undesired changes, and there's probably a better way depending on the font. If xelatex, then search the log file for `unicode-math` or `mathspec` and tell us whether either or both of those appear.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your instruction. I modified my question.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for your instruction. I modified my question. I run it with `xelatex`.

Comment: @Y.zeng But you didn't do what Barbara or I asked! Moreover, the 5's in the image are identical, so it doesn't demonstrate your problem at all. This is most unhelpful. Please look at the log and/or the cls file and look for `unicode-math` or `mathspec`. Also try searching the .cls file for something like `\setmainfont` to see what options it has.

Comment: @frabjous The `55` is clearly different from `555` in the picture, or you can see it by enlarging it. I modified my questions again in which I inserted the codes as you suggested.

Comment: The 55 and 555 as shown in the image posted here have exactly the same 5, so something must have gone wrong in preparing that image.  Are you using non-public fonts on your system?

Comment: @barbarabeeton No he's right. If you zoom in far enough I can see a difference, though it's *very* subtle.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please see the picture I modified. The upper right of `55` is different from the upper right of `555`.

Comment: The math font is XITS Math. When I compile `whu-thesis-demo.tex` I get an identical 5 to its 5 in the text as well, but this is *probably* because I'm on Linux and don't have a system Times or Times New Roman installed, which is what I suspect you're getting. Tom's answer below should work if you want the similar TeX Gyre Termes, but if not, you could either put `\setmainfont{XITS}` right after `\begin{document}` to change the text font to match the math, or put `\setmathfont[range/up{num}]{Times New Roman}` (or maybe just {Times} on a mac?) after `\begin{document}` to change the math digits.

Comment: Or of course use the options explained in the guide to similar effect...

Comment: @frabjous I want to change the math number font to match the text number, so I add `\setmathfont[range/up{num}]{Times New Roman}` after `\begin{document}` as `\begin{document}
\setmathfont[range/up{num}]{Times New Roman}
%%----------- 主体部分 ----------- %%
\include{pages/chapter1}
%\include{pages/chapter2}
%\include{pages/chapter3}
%\include{pages/chapter4}
\end{document}`. But errors shows: `LaTeX3 Error: The key 'fontspec-opentype/up{num}' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored. \include`

Comment: @frabjous Your idea is the right way to resolve the problem. But, how to successfully set numbers in equations to `times new roman` is difficult.

Comment: Sorry. The command is `\setmathfont[range=up/{num}]{Times New Roman}` not  `\setmathfont[range/up{num}]{Times New Roman}`. I can't test that because I don't have that font. It's a proprietary Microsoft font, and proprietary stuff is best avoided when there are just as good open license alternatives.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for your instruction. Your way is totally right and good, which resolve the problem succuessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the template for your university? If yes, you don't need to change it at all. Because this the default setting for the template. If you really want change it, everything you need was written in the [doc](https://github.com/whutug/whu-thesis/blob/v0.6e/whu-thesis-doc.pdf). You should read it carefully before you use the template.

This is the way to make text number match math number. Add this in your preamble:

```
\whusetup{    
    style =
      {
        font=termes,
        math-font=termes,
      },
}
```

If you use Windows, you can do this to make math number match the text number (times new roman). Add this to your preamble:

```
\whusetup{    
    style =
      {
        math-font=none,
      },
}

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[range={scr,bfscr},StylisticSet=01]
\setmathfont[range=up/{num}]{Times New Roman}
```

Comment: This is an official template but one created by students or teachers. If there is something weird, I feel I should change it to the correct status.

Comment: I did it as you saied `style              =
      {
       math-font=termes,
        graphics-path  = {{figures/}{data/}},
      %  list-of-figures,
     %   list-of-tables,
        bib-backend    = biblatex,
      },`, but the number in equation is not same as that in text.

Comment: @Y.zeng Which operation system you use? Try `font=termes, math-font=termes,`

Comment: I am using Windows 11. `font=termes, math-font=termes,` can resolve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I find this way is changing the text number to match the equation number. Is there a way to change the eqaution number to match the text number?

Comment: @Y.zeng I think if you don't change main font , it will use times new roman. You could find a similar math font close to times new roman number.  It was strange, in my machine, if I didn't do anything, I can not reproduce you problem. I got similar 5 for text and math. I am wondering if you correctly install the `unicode-math` package?

Comment: I installed `unicode-math` package. Is there a way to set math number to `times new roman`?

Comment: Could you try delete those two settings `font=termes, math-font=termes` and directly use `\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}` and
   `\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[range={scr,bfscr},StylisticSet=01]` in your preamble.

Comment: I did as you said, but the equation number is different from the text number as before.

Comment: maybe update all your installed packages

Comment: I insert `\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}` and `\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[range={scr,bfscr},StylisticSet=01]` in `cls` file, then all the number in text and in equations are same, but the numbers in `tabularray` table is `times new roman`. Is there a way to change `times new roman` in `tabularray` table as text numbers?

Comment: If we can't change numbers in equations to match text numbers, inserting `font=termes, math-font=termes,` to change text numbers to match equations numbers may be the best way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Because time new roman don't have a math font. Maybe try to change all to termes is the way.

Comment: That's the reason. But, how did you know `times new roman` doesn't have a math font? How about `[range/up{num}]{Times New Roman}` in math?

Comment: As `times new roman` is ttf not otf font, so what `times new roman` can do and what can't?

Comment: @Y.zeng I think I found a way to do that, see the updated answer.

Comment: I tested that only adding `\setmathfont[range=up/{num}]{Times New Roman}` after the `begin{document}` can resolve this problem. Thanks for your reminder.